# How to limit access to backend services behind a gateway service?

Tags: node.js, security, api-gateway, gateway

I build a FE interface, a gateway service, and 2 other backend services. The project is limited to logged-in users, there should be no public access to the data.

Currently, I use the gateway service to handle login, logout, and authorization. All the FE requests go through the gateway service, and if authorized they are forwarded to the 2 other backend services.

Problem is: I wanted to deploy and test with AWS / AppRunner, but just realized beforehand that anybody could actually bypass the gateway service and directly call the 2 backend services without authorization. Oups...

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly protect the access to those 2 backend services. Unfortunately, I cant find a way to limit the requests to ONLY those requests that go through the authorization middleware in the gateway service.

Should I just remove authorization from the gateway service and implement it in all the two backend services? Or would there be any smarter way that would avoid code repetition?

I'm a little confused because in all the tutorials I read, they put authorization in the gateway service but now I don't see how it protects anything.

(I asked the question on Reddit and got a few one-line answers without much explanation: "API keys", "AWS security groups" - I do use AWS -, ... so currently exploring those)